# Calculate Bernoulli numbers ( with a twist)

Tags: equation-solving, summation, recursion, fun

Mathematica has an inbuilt function `BernoulliB` that calculates $B_n$ for which,

$$\frac{t} {\left(e^t-1\right)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{B_n}{n !}t^n  $$

I need to calculate $B_{2j}$ for any positive integer $j$ such that,

$$\frac{t}{e^t-1}=1-\frac{t}{2}+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{B_{2 j}}{(2 j) !} t^{2 j}$$

How do I do this with Mathematica?

Comment: `BernoulliB[2j]`?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: This is written in the documentation: "For odd , the Bernoulli numbers are equal to 0, except B[1]=-1/2 ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I will show how to compute the Bernoulli numbers in a way that generalizes to B2j.

To get $B_n$ you can power-expand $t/(e^t-1)$ about $t=0$; the result is a polynomial with coefficients $B_n/n!$.  You can get any particular coefficient using `SeriesCoefficient` and then multiply it by n! to isolate $B_n$.  That leads to

```
Table[{
    BernoulliB[n],
    n! SeriesCoefficient[t/(Exp[t] - 1), {t, 0, n}]
    }, {n, 0, 20}]
```

which produces identical pairs of numbers, one using the Mathematica built-in and one doing the power expansion.

Therefore, by analogy, you are looking for

```
yourB[j_]:= (2 j)! SeriesCoefficient[t/(Exp[t] - 1) - 1 + t/2, {t, 0, 2 j}]
```

The first few are found by `Table[yourB[j], {j, 0, 10}]`,

```
{0, 1/6, -(1/30), 1/42, -(1/30), 5/66, -(691/2730), 7/6, -(3617/510), 43867/798, -(174611/330)}
```

Comment: Thanks. Please see my answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the built-in `BernoulliB[2j]` you can roll your own $\beta_j=B_{2j}$ with a recursion relation:

```
Clear[β];
β[0] = 1;
β[1] = 1/6;
β[j_] := β[j] = -Sum[Binomial[2j, 2k] β[k] β[j-k], {k, j-1}] / (2j+1)
```

Try it out:

```
Table[β[j] == BernoulliB[2j], {j, 0, 20}]
(*    {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,
       True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,  True}    *)
```

Even simpler in your case would be a recursion relation for $\gamma_j=B_{2j}/(2j)!$ because it does not require binomial weights in the sum:

```
Clear[γ];
γ[0] = 1;
γ[1] = 1/12;
γ[j_] := γ[j] = -Sum[γ[k] γ[j-k], {k, j-1}] / (2j + 1)

Table[γ[j] == BernoulliB[2j]/(2j)!, {j, 0, 20}]
(*    {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,
       True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,  True}    *)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first two terms of $\frac{B_n}{n !}t^n$ are precisely $1$ and $-t/2$. Hence $B_{2j}=BernoulliB[2j]$, for any positive integer $j$.

Comment: Of course I agree, I just assumed you were asking as one example of a general problem.